# Initiate a call in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-broadcast

I am trying out a customized Incoming and outgoing call screen for my app. Both about the same screen and change the buttons according to state received from the broadcast.

I am able to receive incoming calls properly but for making calls when I open my contacts and then click on number my customized screen opens but I don't see it making the call.

I tried the following:

```
        String uri = "tel:" + incomingnumber.trim();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
```

This just makes the call from the default phone dialer and doesn't show my screen.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.AcceptCall"
        android:priority="999"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.PhoneListenerBroad"
        android:priority="999" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Can somebody help me fix the outgoing call part? I would like get my customized screen with call going through?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may try adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE

Comment: I have added the permissions. Strangely it is didn't show up in my question.. I have updated it now..

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the [CALL_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE) permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

Your manifest should look like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> <!-- permission added!-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.AcceptCall"
        android:priority="999"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.honey.ringer.PhoneListenerBroad"
        android:priority="999" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```